# Node how to make dependency analysis and remove unused module dependecies

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

My node modules is a simple module that have few dependencies and makes use mostly of built-in modules.
Given that, my module has a dependency of a module that declares those dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "geocoder": "^0.2.2",
    "gpsoauthnode": "^0.0.5",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.4",
    "protobufjs": "^5.0.1",
    "request": "^2.73.0",
    "s2geometry-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tape": "^4.6.0"
  }
```

Running `npm install` will end up in the following `node_submodules` tree

```
├─┬ body-parser@1.15.2 
│ ├── bytes@2.4.0 
│ ├── content-type@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1 
│ ├── depd@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.5.0 
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1 
│ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.0.1 
│ │ └── statuses@1.3.0 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.13 
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
│ ├── qs@6.2.0 
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.1.7 
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.13 
│   └── media-typer@0.3.0 
├─┬ express@4.14.0 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1 
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1 
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.1 
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1 
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1 
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
│ ├── etag@1.7.0 
│ ├── finalhandler@0.5.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.3.0 
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1 
│ ├── methods@1.1.2 
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.2 
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.1.1 
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0 
│ ├─┬ send@0.14.1 
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4 
│ │ └── mime@1.3.4 
│ ├── serve-static@1.11.1 
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
│ └── vary@1.1.0 
├─┬ pokemon-go-node-api@1.3.1
│ ├── events@1.1.1 
│ ├─┬ geocoder@0.2.2 
│ │ ├─┬ request@2.11.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.0.3 
│ │ │ │ ├── async@0.1.9 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ combined-stream@0.0.3 
│ │ │ │   └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
│ │ │ └── mime@1.2.7 
│ │ ├── underscore@1.3.3 
│ │ └─┬ xml2js@0.2.0 
│ │   └── sax@1.2.1 
│ ├─┬ gpsoauthnode@0.0.5 
│ │ └── crypto-js@3.1.6 
│ ├─┬ istanbul@0.4.4 
│ │ ├── abbrev@1.0.9 
│ │ ├── async@1.5.2 
│ │ ├─┬ escodegen@1.8.0 
│ │ │ ├── estraverse@1.9.3 
│ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2 
│ │ │ ├─┬ optionator@0.8.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── deep-is@0.1.3 
│ │ │ │ ├── fast-levenshtein@1.1.4 
│ │ │ │ ├── levn@0.3.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── prelude-ls@1.1.2 
│ │ │ │ └── type-check@0.3.2 
│ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.2.0 
│ │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── esprima@2.7.2 
│ │ ├─┬ fileset@0.2.1 
│ │ │ └─┬ minimatch@2.0.10 
│ │ │   └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
│ │ │     ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
│ │ │     └── concat-map@0.0.1 
│ │ ├─┬ handlebars@4.0.5 
│ │ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10 
│ │ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
│ │ │ ├── source-map@0.4.4 
│ │ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.7.0 
│ │ │   ├── async@0.2.10 
│ │ │   ├── source-map@0.5.6 
│ │ │   └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
│ │ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.6.1 
│ │ │ └─┬ argparse@1.0.7 
│ │ │   └── sprintf-js@1.0.3 
│ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ │ ├── nopt@3.0.6 
│ │ ├─┬ once@1.3.3 
│ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2 
│ │ ├── resolve@1.1.7 
│ │ ├─┬ supports-color@3.1.2 
│ │ │ └── has-flag@1.0.0 
│ │ ├─┬ which@1.2.10 
│ │ │ └── isexe@1.1.2 
│ │ └── wordwrap@1.0.0 
│ ├─┬ protobufjs@5.0.1 
│ │ ├─┬ ascli@1.0.0 
│ │ │ ├── colour@0.7.1 
│ │ │ └── optjs@3.2.2 
│ │ ├─┬ bytebuffer@5.0.1 
│ │ │ └── long@3.2.0 
│ │ ├─┬ glob@5.0.15 
│ │ │ ├── inflight@1.0.5 
│ │ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
│ │ └─┬ yargs@3.10.0 
│ │   ├── camelcase@1.2.1 
│ │   ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0 
│ │   │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.4 
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@3.0.3 
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.3 
│ │   │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1 
│ │   │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.5.4 
│ │   │ │ └── lazy-cache@1.0.4 
│ │   │ ├── right-align@0.1.3 
│ │   │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2 
│ │   ├── decamelize@1.2.0 
│ │   └── window-size@0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ s2geometry-node@1.3.1 
│ │ └── bindings@1.2.1 
│ └─┬ tape@4.6.0 
│   ├── deep-equal@1.0.1 
│   ├── defined@1.0.0 
│   ├── function-bind@1.1.0 
│   ├─┬ glob@7.0.5 
│   │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
│   │ └── minimatch@3.0.2 
│   ├── has@1.0.1 
│   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│   ├── object-inspect@1.2.1 
│   ├── resumer@0.0.0 
│   ├─┬ string.prototype.trim@1.1.2 
│   │ ├─┬ define-properties@1.1.2 
│   │ │ ├── foreach@2.0.5 
│   │ │ └── object-keys@1.0.11 
│   │ └─┬ es-abstract@1.5.1 
│   │   ├─┬ es-to-primitive@1.1.1 
│   │   │ ├── is-date-object@1.0.1 
│   │   │ └── is-symbol@1.0.1 
│   │   ├── is-callable@1.1.3 
│   │   └── is-regex@1.0.3 
│   └── through@2.3.8 
├─┬ request@2.74.0 
│ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
│ ├── aws4@1.4.1 
│ ├─┬ bl@1.1.2 
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6 
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7 
│ │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31 
│ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│ ├── caseless@0.11.0 
│ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
│ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
│ ├── extend@3.0.0 
│ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
│ ├── form-data@1.0.0-rc4 
│ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
│ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
│ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0 
│ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
│ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
│ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
│ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
│ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 
│ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2 
│ │ │ ├── jsonpointer@2.0.0 
│ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1 
│ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
│ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4 
│ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
│ │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
│ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
│ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
│ │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
│ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
│ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
│ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.3.0 
│ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2 
│ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2 
│ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6 
│ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.8.3 
│ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
│ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.14.0 
│ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
│ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.6 
│ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
│ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2 
│ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0 
│ │   └── tweetnacl@0.13.3 
│ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
│ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
│ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
│ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.11 
│ │ └── mime-db@1.23.0 
│ ├── node-uuid@1.4.7 
│ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2 
│ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
│ ├── tough-cookie@2.3.0 
│ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.3 
└─┬ tough-cookie-filestore@0.0.1 
  └─┬ tough-cookie@0.12.1 
    └── punycode@2.0.0
```

that is nothing less than

```
node_modules admin$ du -d0 -h
 40M    .
```

40Meg, what? At first look I was a bit surprised of that, since the list of dependencies seems to be too much. I would expect something like that from the `Makefile` of low level C library like `Boost`, `libcrypto`, `libxml`, `libssl` or whatever C/C++ library used by an OS, but, hey wait a moment, this is just a simple application using built-in library and just one external dependency. So, what's going on here?

Being serious, my question is: is there a way to make a static analysis of `node` packages installed via `npm`? And then to prune unused dependencies? 
For sure, my module will not use at runtime most of the function declarations in the private scope of each of those modules, defined in this tree.